# Auth0 Get userId in response payload?

Tags: auth0

When a user logins using the Auth0 lock on my client side, I get an idToken, but also an idTokenPayload which looks like this:

```
idTokenPayload = {
  audience: "AUTH0CLIENTID",
  exp: 1494190538,
  iat: 1494154538,
  iss: "AUTH0DOMAIN"
  sub: "USERNAME"
};
```

Would it be possible to return the userId in Auth0's database instead of the username in the `sub` field?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to keep Auth0's db for users, and I have on my server-side some Profile, Post, Comment etc entities which have a `userId` column. Right now before each request on my entities I need to populate the user by doing an extra request: `let id = Profile.find("... where username === auth0.sub").getId();` (pseudo-code of course).

Answer (score 0):

With the C# lock sdk, you get back an Auth0User after the call to the LoginAsync method in the Auth0 client. Let's call this variable auth0User. If I look at auth0User.Profile, a JObject (it's a JSON object if you're not using C#), it contains a JSON array named "identities". My identities variable initialization  looks like:

```
var identities = (JArray)auth0User.Profile["identities"];
```

This array contains all the identity providers associated with the user. If like me you haven't attached any other sign in besides Auth0, there will be just 1 entry here. Each object in this JSON array will contain a "provider" string and a "user_id" string. If the provider says "auth0" then it's from Auth0. Since I don't use FB or other account types I'm not exactly sure what they say. Here's my C# code to get the UserID:

```
var identities = (JArray)auth0User.Profile["identities"];
        if (identities != null)
        {
            foreach (var identity in identities)
            {
                var provider = (string)identity["provider"];
                if (string.Equals(provider, "auth0"))
                {
                    UserID = (string)identity["user_id"];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I believe that this should all be provided standard without needing to add any rules or webhooks. This article should explain in more detail and also gives examples in javascript: [auth0 normalized user profile](https://auth0.com/docs/user-profile/normalized)